# Mocking code first Entity Framework entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have a class like this

```
   public class FooEntity
   {
        private BarEntity Bar;

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var result = Bar.DoSomethingElse();

            if (result)
                DoThis();

            else
                DoThat();

        }

        private void DoThis() { }

        private void DoThat() { }
   }
```

I'm trying to test FooEntity.  From a unit test perspective, I want to mock BarEntity out and provide a test result, because I'm not testing BarEntity.

Every mocking framework I've seen seems to require interfaces for mocks.  Using interfaces as navigation properties in Entity Framework isn't supported last I checked.  I get that I can just add a unmapped property to the entity of my interface type and use that.  It seems kinda cumbersome to do that just to satisfy some tests.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If Foo is an EF entity I'd keep it simple. No methods.

Comment: What sets the Bar?

Comment: @mayu: That's what I struggle with. I've always kept entities (Java) consisting of fields, getters, and setters -- no methods.  Most of the code I've seen in that fashion has virtually no domain model.  There are service classes that just manipulate the properties on the entities.  I was trying to add some behavior to the entities themselves without having to map back and forth from a separate domain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Moq;

public class FooEntity
{
    //if Bar is a table, you should write like this:
    public virtual BarEntity Bar {get;set;}
    public int BarId {get;set;}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var result = Bar.DoSomethingElse();

        if (result)
            DoThis();
        else
            DoThat();
    }

    private void DoThis() { }
    private void DoThat() { }
}

var mock = new Mock<BarEntity>();
//DoSomethingElse method should be virtual and BarEntity should not be sealed
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomethingElse()).Returns(true);//or false
var target2test = new FooEntity { Bar = mock.Object };
//action:
target2test.DoSomething();//will result to DoThis calling
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I'm a Java guy just getting into c#.  Didn't realize the properties had to be virtual in order to mock.  Thanks again.